# json creation in forEach throwing exception

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a json from a `forEach` loop and the code is as below.

```js
var data = [{
  "name": "A",
  "id": 1
}, {
  "name": "B",
  "id": 2
}, {
  "name": "C",
  "id": 3
}];
var data2 = [];
var data3=[];
data.forEach(item => data2.push({
  'Hi': "Hi"
}));
console.log(data2);
console.log('========================');
/*
data.forEach(item => data3.push({
  item.id: item.name
}));
console.log(data3);
*/
```

When I uncomment the commented block, It is throwing me an error.

I'm trying to create a JSON like

```
[{
    "1": "A"
  },
  {
    "2": "B"
  },
  {
    "3": "C"
  }
]
```

Please let me know where am I going wrong.

Thanks

Comment: **forEach** does not `return` anything , use **map** or modify in place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `push` you can use `map`:

```js
const data = [{
  "name": "A",
  "id": 1
}, {
  "name": "B",
  "id": 2
}, {
  "name": "C",
  "id": 3
}];
const result = data.map(item => ({
  [item.id]: item.name
}));
console.log(result);

// But if for any reason you still prefer to use push you can do it like this
const result2 = [];
data.forEach(item => result2.push({
  [item.id]: item.name
}));
console.log(result2);
```

Comment: Hey @Mehran, why use map rather push? Apologies for asking this basic question

Comment: @user3872094 when you want to transform elements in an array it is recommended to use map. And if you read the code you are actually mapping the values of an array to a new array with the same length. When using foreach you have to manually create an array and mutate that array by iterating over another array while using map you only specify how do you want to map the elements of one array to another one which makes it more readable as well. I recommend reading this post to learn more about map: [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

Answer (score 1):

Do this with the commented block:

```js
data.forEach(item => data3.push({
  [item.id]: item.name
}));
```

This way the compiler knows that the key value is dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

try this ,just use `[item.id]` in place of static keys

```js
var data = [{
  "name": "A",
  "id": 1
}, {
  "name": "B",
  "id": 2
}, {
  "name": "C",
  "id": 3
}];
var data2 = [];
var data3 = [];
data.forEach(item => data2.push({
  [item.id]: item.name
}));
console.log(data2);
console.log('========================');
/*
data.forEach(item => data3.push({
  item.id: item.name
}));
console.log(data3);
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

**forEach** does not return anything , use **map** or modify in place

```
var data = [{
  "name": "A",
  "id": 1
}, {
  "name": "B",
  "id": 2
}, {
  "name": "C",
  "id": 3
}];
var data2 = [];
var data3=[];
data.forEach(function(item,index){
    const tmp = {};
    tmp[ item.id ] = item.name;
    data2[ index ] = tmp;
})
console.log(data2);
console.log('========================');
/*
data.forEach(item => data3.push({
  item.id: item.name
}));
console.log(data3);
*/
```